# Display.getInstance().callSerially

Tags: java-me

I'm new to J2ME, in lots of places I have seen this: `Display.getInstance().callSerially`..

e.g.

```
Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    startThread();
  }
});
```

why we need to use this?what is the advantage?please anyone explain me..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reading the lengthy explanations in the javadoc-api?

There are several paragraphs in the `javax.microedition.lcdui.Display#callSerially(java.lang.Runnable)` apidoc and even a code sample explaining why and how this is to be used